# Change NFS from async to sync on linux for VMware client with no downtime

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, nfs, network-attached-storage

So I just discovered that my client's linux-based NFS storage server (CentOS 6.5) is exporting storage to VMware (vSphere 5) with the async option in exportfs.

Is it possible to change that to sync and do an 'exportfs -r -a' without causing any downtime on the VMware servers?

In theory that should be fine, but theory is theory. Anyone done something like this?

As a note: The stated reason for this is that the server has a BBU. I don't imagine that should have any bearing on whether they should use sync or not. In my mind, a BBU with write back should just speed up sync writes.